# InputDatePickerFormField: how to get its value without form?

Tags: flutter

InputDatePickerFormField: how to get its value without form?

```
InputDatePickerFormField(
            firstDate: firstDate,
            lastDate: lastDate,
            onDateSaved: (value) {
              date = value;
            },
            onDateSubmitted: (value) {
              date = value;
            },
          ),
```

No callback on losing focus. Is there a way to get the value without Form?

Comment: If you check the source code of `InputDatePickerFormField` it's just a simple customization on `TextFormField`, you can implement a similar functionality with `TextField`

Comment: Looking at its source code. It has _controller (TextEditingController) but it is private. Its build method return TextFormField. Wondering if a FocusNode can be attached to it to catch "LoseFocus" event and get the date value. Thanks.

Comment: From widget inspector, the InputDatePickerFormField is a leaf and does not show its child TextFormField. Is there a way to get its child widget TextFormField? Thanks.

Comment: Yes actually the only problem is that the controller is private (which is by design, obviously), so what I think is that you create a totally new class in your codebase that mimics how it's implemented

Comment: The controller should be public for developers to use all the features of TextFormField. Thanks.

Comment: Nah, I can see why they decided to make it private, so that no one will break the form behavior and not use it in an improper way (which is exactly what you're trying to do here :D). TextField exists anyway, and that's the intended way if you want to have more control on that